# What exactly happens when I use "scanf"?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand what happens when I'm using the "scanf" function, or to be more specific, what happen when I'm trying to enter letter into int with "scanf".

So I understood that when I'm trying to input letter into int, it's just doesn't work, so i wrote this to check what happends:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num=0;
    char term='a';
    scanf("%d%c", &num, &term);
    printf("%d%c", num, term);
 
    return 0;
}
```

When my input is "b" for example, the output is "0a", while I excepted it to be "0b" becouse the "scanf" would not entered "b" into num, and then he would entered it into "term".

Does someone know why its happens? I looked for answer and saw that its connect with the buffer but still I didn't understand what's happened.

Comment: Spend 1 hour learning from [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (all of it) paying particular attention to *match count*, *matching failure* and *input failure*. Learning `scanf()` (really learning it) will save you hours and hours of frustration later. ALWAYS check the return of EVERY input function used. Never assume blindly that input succeeds. Otherwise you invite *Undefined Behavior* when you use a variable you thought contained data but doesn't. They you will know why `fgets()` into a buffer and parsing with `sscanf()` is superior to `scanf()` alone....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you input a non-digit character when a digit is expected (like for the `%d` format) then `scanf` will fail *immediately*.

Similarly for other formats and mismatching inputs, as soon as invalid input is detected the function will fail and return.

You should always check what `scanf` [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

When `scanf` fails, it will *leave* the input in the buffer. So next time you read you will get that data.

Comment: So u means that when I wrote  "scanf("%d%c", &num, &term);"  it will stop right after it fail to input "b" into "num"?

Comment: Becouse when I'm writing "scanf("%d", &num);
    scanf("%c", &term);" it's work as I expected.

Comment: @AlfaHores That's because the input-buffer will be left-alone, leaving the `b` in the buffer for the *next* input operation.